# Выборка из двух таблиц с суммированием столбца

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица clients и transactions. В обеих таблицах есть столбец client_id. Как вы уже поняли в таблице clients хранятся данные клиента (ФИО, адрес и т п) а в таблице transactions данные оплаты каждого клиента. Нужно вывести на страницу сумму столбца sum которая есть в таблице transactions по отдельности для каждого клиента.  Например клиент Сидоров 3 раза оплатил по 1000 руб. что в итоге нужно вывести рядом с его именем сумму 3000 руб. И т д. Пробую так :

```
SELECT client_id, SUM(p.sum) total FROM transactions p GROUP by p.client_id
```

На phpmyadmin выводит отлично. Но как взять и остальные данные клиента из таблицы clients и вывести это на страницу через PHP ? Подскажите, друзья

Общая картина выглядет так

```
<?php 

                $sum_query= "SELECT client_id, SUM(p.sum) total FROM transactions p GROUP by p.client_id" ;
                    $result100 = mysqli_query($con,$sum_query)   or die(mysqli_error($con));    
                    while($row100 = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result100 )) { 

                    $total = $row100["total"];

                    }
                ?>
```

И переменную $total пытаюсь пихнуть в другой цикл где вывожу данные клиента из таблицы clients в виде HTML таблицы. Я понимаю что это так не делается, но не знаю как...

При запросе `SELECT p.client_id, SUM(p.sum) total FROM transactions p JOIN jclients as b WHERE p.client_id=b.client_id GROUP by b.client_id`
 он выводит вот это :  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал так 
`SELECT p.client_id,
      p.name,
      p.sname,
      SUM(c.sum) Total
    FROM jclients p LEFT JOIN
       transactions c ON p.client_id = c.client_id
    GROUP BY p.client_id`

и всё заработало ! Спасибо, Mike

Comment: добавить в запрос обычный join таблицы с клиентами. в часть select добавить требуемые столбцы из clients и их же в group by

Comment: SELECT client_id, SUM(p.sum) total FROM transactions p JOIN jclients as b WHERE p.client_id=b.client_id  GROUP by p.client_id
Попытался сделать так пишет #1052 - Столбец 'client_id' в field list задан неоднозначно

Comment: `SELECT p.client_id` (добавил 'p' указатель на таблицу откуда брать)

Comment: Да, но он по прежнему не берет Имя клиента из таблицы jclients что нужно добавить чтоб он и имена вытаскивал из соседней таблицы ? подскажите пожалуйста